# Android: can exceptions be thrown from SQLite database during transactions?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Suppose I have two threads that need to perform atomic Read-Mofify-Write operations on SQLite database (in Android).

In order to ensure atomicity, I'm wrapping the logic with database transactions:

```
try {
    database.beginTransaction();
    ... read-modify-write logic here
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally {
    database.endTransaction();
}
```

This transaction is EXCLUSIVE by default (at least it is on Android). Performance (throughput) is not a factor (client side - not many transactions expected).

Until now all good, but one issue bothers me: while the above `try-finally` pattern will ensure database's consistency in case of a thrown exception, if an exception really happens to be thrown and I don't catch it - my app will crash...

When it comes to my own code I know which exceptions can be thrown and how to handle them, but I tried to understand which exceptions can be thrown by SQLite database itself in this case (if any), but I can't find it documented in any place.

So, my questions with respect to the above code are:

1. Which fatal exceptions can be thrown when single thread executes this code (fatal = irrecoverable; let the application crash)?
2. Which non-fatal exceptions can be thrown when single thread executes this code and how can I handle them?
3. If one thread already in transaction and another thread attempts to start a new transaction, will the second thread just block until the first one finishes, or will exception be thrown?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the database operations, all sorts of constraint violations might happen, but those usually indicate a programming error.
Furthermore, reading or write the database file can run into any random hardware error, which can result in any random exception.

Finally, if the database is locked for too long, you get a "database is locked" exception. You can adjust the waiting time for a specific connection with [PRAGMA busy_timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) (the default value is not useful).

Comment: Oh my, I should've thought about constraints violations myself... Can you also help me clarify "severities"? 1) It is my decision whether constraint violation is fatal or recoverable, right? 2) The hardware errors that you mention can probably be considered rare fatal errors and ignored (i.e. app crash), right? 3) If I understood correctly, "database locked" exception will be thrown for waiting thread if it waits for too long, right? I'd say that this indicates an implementation error and can be treated as fatal (my app is not critical system)? THanks

Comment: You cannot handle errors that you do not know. "Too long" depends.

Comment: Understood. Thank you